# Need to resize div to fit text as it overflows due to continuously reducing viewport size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like my div to expand in height to fit the text as when it starts overflowing (as I reduce the browser size). I want it to be a smooth increase in height as required by the content when the browser width is reduced smoothly from 1363px to 320px.

Please help. Will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

```css
.centrediv {
  style="width:54%;
 position: absolute;
  top: 26%;
  bottom: 45%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgba(229, 240, 247, 0.75);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: #f0fafb;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="centrediv">
  <h2 style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;opacity:1;font-size:22px;">
    Hi,
    <span>
      <br>
      <br>
    </span>
    We are a 
    <span>
      <a href="/courses/team/">XYZ based team</a>
    </span>
    some random text that initially fits the div at max browser size but starts overflowing from the div as the browser/viewport size is reduced.
    <span>
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span>
      <a href="/courses/product/">Know more.</a>
    </span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce from existing code...

Comment: Remove the absolute positioning and it will resize as expected.... and what is `.centrediv {  style="width:54%;` ??? That's all kinds of incorrect.

Comment: Hey, thanks actually that did the trick. And that style thing was a mistake that I overlooked. I add quick styles into the html while working to fix a thing or two and then bring it back into the css sections when reviewing. I missed this one. Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Should this be marked as resolved?